# How to disable delete action in List view in react admin?

Tags: react-admin

Before version 2 you could just not pass `remove` prop to `<Resource/>` component. However now delete action is included by default in `<List/>` view and I can't find anywhere in docs how I can disable it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<Datagrid/>` component has `bulkActionButtons` prop, where you can customize how bulk actions work. Here is the [link to docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/4.2/Datagrid.html#bulkactionbuttons)

If you are using the version 3 or lower you can provide the `bulkActionButtons` to the `<List />` component.

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/00ffc81e27d19b5242c93c28eb8b6668928439a0/docs/Upgrade.md#list-bulkactionbuttons-prop-moved-to-datagrid

Answer (score 15):

Putting `false` to `bulkActionButtons` of `List` disables bulk actions.

```js
<List bulkActionButtons={false}>
  ..
</List>
```

transGLUKator mentioned about `bulkActionButtons` but it took time for me to find value to disable bulk actions.

Reference

Source code of List of react-admin: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/93bc43fcec652e6c2eaaa2dc7bdf45b2f64e12fb/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/list/List.js#L128

Answer (score 1):

The `<List>` `bulkActionButtons` prop is now deprecated—instead you use it directly on `<DataGrid>`, e.g.

```
<List>
  <Datagrid bulkActionButtons={false}>
    …
  </Datagrid>
</List>
```

[See the `DataGrid` `bulkActionButtons` docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html#bulkactionbuttons)